# L4: Mail::queue error Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I got an error when I replace `send` to `queue` in sending emails. Here's my code:

```
foreach ($recs as $rec)
{
     $em = $rec->email;

      Mail::queue('emails.newsletter',$data,
              function($message) use(&$em) {
              $message->to($em)->subject('Newsletter | Bla Bla');
      });   
}
```

My mail Driver is smtp and the host is `relay-hosting.secureserver.net` from godaddy.

It works fine if I'll use `Mail::send` rather than `Mail::queue`

Comment: check that your using a valid email address

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that all of your emails used are valid, my guess is that it occurs because you are using the & operator (reference) in foreach and you dont unset it afterwards, below a snippet from the foreach php docs

```
 Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().
```

While you are using the queue that most probably consumes the job later on (not instantly as ::send) it's not fetching what it should (because of messed up reference) - so you feed the mailer with an empty email address - that's why you get the validation error.

Firstly, I think you don't need the reference at all, so just remove the & operator

```
function($message) use($em) {
```

Secondly, take a read here [References and foreach](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and worked it around by passing all data by value. BTW, it is recommended to pass only values to queued Closures to avoid unexpected serialization behavior.

```
foreach ($recs as $rec)
{
    $em = $rec->email;

    Mail::queue(
        'emails.newsletter',
        $data,
        function($message) use ($em) {
            $message->to($em)->subject('Newsletter | Bla Bla');
        }
    );   
}
```